# Do routers and firewalls block HTTPS traffic on port 80?

Tags: networking, firewall, gateway

I've encountered a scenario where some devices are using HTTPS on port 80, but various routers and firewalls configured with a port forward for 80 are not passing HTTPS traffic.

I know some commercial or quality routers/firewalls will include application layer gateways which may block non-HTTP traffic on port 80.

Is it reasonable to expect any router to do this, and thus avoid using HTTPS on port 80 (i.e. change the device settings)?

Are there other reasons to avoid using port 80 in this way?

**Edit:**

One of several routers I am using is a Cradlepoint IBR600LE. Some sensors behind it <strike>publish</strike> provide data (acting as servers) on port 80 using HTTP. When we enable HTTPS on the sensors (and data collection program that communicates with them), and leave everything else the same, we can no longer reach them. If we change the port to just about anything else (along with the port forward), it works. This has led me to conclude that the router is blocking or redirecting HTTPS, but I am not sure how to find that setting or determine what is really happening.

Comment: Related on SO: [Do firewalls block non-HTTP traffic on port 80?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10614318/161052)

Comment: It would be very unsual for a router or firewall to block port 80/443 doing so would basically block all traffic on the device.  Are you sure your not simply being caught up by content filtering instead?

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on those "various routers" and the environment this whole endeavor is taking place in. Right now your questions seems sort of... unfocused? I guess.

Comment: @DanielB Sorry - I'll add some more detail.

Comment: Extremely unlikely. It is not very clear to be whether your sensors behind Cradlepoint is acting as client or server (as you used the word "publish" along with "port forwarding"). The best way is to capture the packets on both client and server and check if packet payload is being altered (besides the L3/L4 headers) or dropped.

Comment: @someuser I understand the confusion. By "publish" I mean the sensors act as servers, not that they "push" data somewhere. I understand how my explanation is misleading. I will edit it further.